# rewrite failing htaccess leading internel server error

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L] 
</IfModule>
```

webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

kindly help

Comment: What url is causing the error?

Comment: I am trying to install a script and it is not install instead it is showing internel server error on desi3x.com

Comment: Do you have access to the apache error logs? Please add it to your question.